# Removing border areas on JFreeChart MultiplePiePlot

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm rendering a `MultiplePiePlot` using JFreeChart, and I'm having trouble controlling colours of background and border areas. In particular, I'd like to hide:

1. The white rectangle to the right (and matching one to the left) of the bottom row of pie plots.
2. The thin vertical white line to the right of the plots, which does not appear on the left.
3. The thin horizontal white line below the plots, which does not appear at the top.

[image: Section of pie plot showing white areas]

My code looks like this:

```
    MultiplePiePlot plot = new MultiplePiePlot(getDataset());

    plot.setNoDataMessage("No data available");
    PiePlot pie = (PiePlot)plot.getPieChart().getPlot();

    pie.setNoDataMessage("No data available");
    pie.setLabelGenerator(null);

    pie.setSectionPaint("Off", Color.GRAY);

    JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(plot);
    chart.setBorderPaint(null);
    plot.setOutlinePaint(chart.getBackgroundPaint());
    plot.getPieChart().setBackgroundPaint(chart.getBackgroundPaint());
```

I've attempted to turn off the border painting, set the outline of the outer chart and the background of the inner chart to the same colour. How do I control areas 1, 2, and 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the risk of hurting your eyes, this code and the chart below it illustrates where the colors come from:

```
chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.YELLOW);
MultiplePiePlot plot = (MultiplePiePlot) chart.getPlot();
plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.BLUE);
JFreeChart subchart = plot.getPieChart();
subchart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.RED);
```

The chart has a yellow background, and contains a single instance of MultiPiePlot with a blue background.  The MultiPiePlot "rubber stamps" 5 individual pie charts (one JFreeChart instance, drawn 5 times), and each of those has a red background.

[image: MultiPiePlot background colors]

Comment: Spot on, thanks. I completely missed that the `MultiplePiePlot` had a background separate from the background of the internal pie chart.